# ThreadPoolExecutor with fix poolsize and many task

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I have a problem with ThreadPoolExecutor. There is a list which contains many file name.
I want to process these files with multithreading. I only want 2 or 4 threads (depends on the processor) in one time. Sometimes if the files are long I get out of memory exception. 
I investigated the problem with no result...

The code:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new   ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 2,
                0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(20));
```

I store the file names in a list then I iterate through the list one-by-one and call the `execute()` method.

```
for(String fileName : fileNames) {
   executor.execute(new FileProcess(fileName));
}
```

Then `shutdown()` the poolThread and wait for every thread are finish.

```
    if (ProjectsHandler.withThread){
        executor.shutdown();
        while(!executor.isTerminated()) {
            // wait until all threads are finish
        }
    }
```

So I gave out of memory exception. The profiler said the cause is the ThreadPoolExecutor.
If I run the program with 1 thread everything is ok, no exception.

What could be the problem? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm assuming that this is a typo - `ThreadPoolExecutor executor + new   ThreadPoolExecutor`

Comment: yepp this was a typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess, I would bet that your `FileProcess` class reads in the entire contents of the file you are processing and stores it in an in-memory collection. I would also guess that you are starting the JVM with the default memory which is not that much.

Try using `-Xmx 1024M` as part of the command line argument to the JVM when you start your program.

Comment: The FileProcess handle the all file reading and processing stuff. I tried with -Xmx and it's worked. I just wondering whether I'm made some mistake in the program or it just consumes memory because of the file size.

Comment: @hcpeter Possibly a little of both, but is it is a safe assumption that you will never encounter a Gigabyte of file data at once, I wouldn't restructure the program. The JVM by default only allows 64M or memory to store not only the program data but also the Thread stack and Class data (bytecode). Even if the program only had one thread, trying to process a file that is 100M would cause the program to fail because the file data is larger than the program memory. PS if an answer works, it is common courtesy to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is anything to do with threading. If you run two tasks in parallel, and they both need 256MB, and you only have 384MB (for example), you'll run out of memory. If you run them sequentially, without threads, you'll be fine (but it'll take longer).

You should look at the cause of the out of memory exception. Try reducing the memory available to the JVM until the single thread version triggers it. That will make it easier to debug.